# ng2-completer with nested dropdown

Tags: angular

I have reactive form like bellow:

component.ts:

```
public colors = ["aliceblue","antiquewhite","aqua","aquamarine","azure","beige",
"bisque","black","blanchedalmond"];


      form = new FormGroup({
          ItemNames: new FormArray([
            new FormControl([null]),
          ])
        });


    onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.ItemNames.value);
      console.log(this.form.value);  
    }
```

component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="form-group row"  formArrayName="ItemNames">
            <div class="col-3 pr-0 border-right-0 with-chevron">
                <ng2-completer *ngFor="let ItemName of ItemNames.controls; let i=index"
                              #openCloseExample
                               class="completer-limit"                       
                               [datasource]="dataService4"
                               [inputClass]="'form-control'"
                               [openOnFocus]="true"
                               (opened)="onOpened($event)"
                               (focus)="openCloseFocused = true"
                               (blur)="openCloseFocused = false"
                               [minSearchLength]="0"
                               [placeholder]="'search color'"
                               [autoHighlight]="true"
                               [fillHighlighted]="false">
                </ng2-completer>
            </div>
```

How can I provide form control name here like `formControlName="i"` in ng2-completetr. I have tried in different ways but no luck until now. Could you please help me for this issue?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do.Mention the purpose of this method so that we can direct you in the right way

Comment: Thanks for asking. I just want to loop the ng2-completer for multiple dropdown value. Problem is I can't assign formcontrol name in ng2-copleter.

Comment: whats the error you are getting when you use formcontrol ?

Comment: It says "Cannot find control with path"

Comment: obviously because you are not assigning any names to the formcontrol.Please go through https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was a fix in ng2-completer now it is working as expected.

It should be like bellow:

```
public colors = ["aliceblue","antiquewhite","aqua","aquamarine","azure","beige",
"bisque","black","blanchedalmond"];


      form = new FormGroup({
          ItemNames: new FormArray([
            new FormControl(null),
          ])
        });


    onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.ItemNames.value);
      console.log(this.form.value);  
    }
```

and

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="form-group row"  formArrayName="ItemNames">
            <div class="col-3 pr-0 border-right-0 with-chevron">
                <ng2-completer *ngFor="let ItemName of ItemNames.controls; let i=index"
                              #openCloseExample
                               formControlName="i"
                               class="completer-limit"                       
                               [datasource]="dataService4"
                               [inputClass]="'form-control'"
                               [openOnFocus]="true"
                               (opened)="onOpened($event)"
                               (focus)="openCloseFocused = true"
                               (blur)="openCloseFocused = false"
                               [minSearchLength]="0"
                               [placeholder]="'search color'"
                               [autoHighlight]="true"
                               [fillHighlighted]="false">
                </ng2-completer>
            </div>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUs1xorNkIU1QF7KTfIb?p=preview)